# Define a clickable/touchable area for custom markers in android google-maps-api-2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, clickable

I'm new to google maps or rather android programming. Nevertheless I just managed to set up a google map for an internet browser. I created several custom markers (markers with my own icon) which have a specific clickable area.

For google maps for internet browsers this down by

```
      var shape = {
      coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
      type: 'poly'
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
      var beach = beaches[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
      });
    }
```

So you define a shape which will be your clickable area of the marker. This works.

Now I like to **develop my google map application for an android device**. I want the same marker icon as I used in google maps for browsers. Though this is not written in JavaScript like before but in Java and I've already done it. But **I can't manage to find an option to create a clickable or rather a touchable area for my custom markers on android google maps**! There is even a larg area around my custom icon and I can't change it.

**So do you know an option how I can define the clickable/touchable area for google map markers for android?** Or is it not possible because the thumb isn't  accurate as a computer mouse?

[Screenshot of my map with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIUKp.jpg)

With kind regards,
Taskmanager

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `OnInfoWindowClickListenerCallback`. There is a method in `GoogleMap` for that:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                //Handle your click here                
        }
        });
```

**Update:**

```
// Set a listener for marker click.    
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

/** Called when the user clicks a marker. */
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    // Retrieve the data from the marker.
    Integer clickCount = (Integer) marker.getTag();

    // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
    if (clickCount != null) {
        clickCount = clickCount + 1;
        marker.setTag(clickCount);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                       marker.getTitle() +
                       " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
    // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
    // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
    return false;
}
```

Refer [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker)  for more details. Also make sure the image you are using for markers does not have padding within it.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I don't have any infowindow because I only need the markers itself. The markers are already clickable and I have a clicklistener for them which works as desired.

The problem is that I can't reduce the size of the marker's clickable/touchable area like with the shape on the browser version. The clickable area is too big.

[Please see my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIUKp.jpg)

Rgds, 
Taskmanager